# Android Studio Layout Problems

Tags: android

Hello i'm learning Kotlin. I wanna try to practise my knowledge and i decided to build calculator like ios. I added linearlayout for my textview, added tablelayout and 4 rows.
Then i put linearlayout for 3 buttons in the bottom. MyTextview is not visible, it stands behind the table layout i couldn't fix it how can fix those design issues ?

My xml codes:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[My LAYOUT PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L41gA.png)

Comment: your question doesn't have anything to do with android studio, as the tag explains, and because you're just asking about layouts the java and kotlin tags aren't needed either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your XML 
add this

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

`android:layout_gravity="center"`

to `TableLayout` ,

`android:layout_gravity="center"`

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

to `TextView` ,

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

to `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot i fixed that while i was coming to delete you added your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: it is great my bro .

Comment: OP has accepted your answer, but you haven't explained to anyone what you've done or what was wrong. it's always a good idea to explain what you've done and not just give code to solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constraint to the TableLayout, because it may be defaulting to aligning with the top of the screen. For example, you can add app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="id of TextView" and android:layout_marginTop="30dp" to the TableLayout element in order to force the TableLayout to be 30dp below the TextView.